# Deserialize complex object using custom XmlSerialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have written following sample code to save a slightly complex object `FamilyTreeFile` to XML and restore it back to original form.

```
public class XmlSerializationTest
{
    const string FileName = @"FamilyTree.xml";

    public void Run()
    {
        var rootMember = new Member() { Name = "Johny", Parent = null };
        var member1 = new Member() { Name = "Andy", Parent = rootMember };
        var member2 = new Member() { Name = "Adam", Parent = rootMember };
        var member3 = new Member() { Name = "Andrew", Parent = rootMember };
        var member4 = new Member() { Name = "Davis", Parent = member2 };
        var member5 = new Member() { Name = "Simon", Parent = member4 };

        rootMember.FamilyTree = new GenericCollection();
        rootMember.FamilyTree.Add(member1);
        rootMember.FamilyTree.Add(member2);
        rootMember.FamilyTree.Add(member3);
        member2.FamilyTree = new GenericCollection();
        member2.FamilyTree.Add(member4);
        member4.FamilyTree = new GenericCollection();
        member4.FamilyTree.Add(member5);

        var familyTree = new GenericCollection() { rootMember };

        IFamilyTreeFile file = new FamilyTreeFile()
        {
            FamilyTree = familyTree
        };

        Serialize(file);
        file = Deserialize();
    }

    public void Serialize(IFamilyTreeFile obj)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FamilyTreeFile));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FileName))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }
    }

    public IFamilyTreeFile Deserialize()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FamilyTreeFile));
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return (IFamilyTreeFile)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}

public interface IMember
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IMember Parent { get; set; }
    GenericCollection FamilyTree { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Member : IMember
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IMember Parent { get; set; }
    public GenericCollection FamilyTree { get; set; }

    public Member()
    {
        //FamilyTree = new GenericCollection();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class GenericCollection : List<IMember>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        if (reader.Name == "FamilyTree")
        {
            do
            {
                reader.Read();
                if (reader.Name == "Member" && reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    Type type = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                    .Where(x => x.Name == reader.Name)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                    if (type != null)
                    {
                        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
                        var member = (IMember)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        this.Add(member);
                    }
                }

                if (reader.Name == "FamilyTree" && reader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                    break;
            }
            while (!reader.EOF);
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (IMember rule in this)
        {
            var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(rule.GetType());
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, rule, namespaces);
        }
    }
}

public interface IFamilyTreeFile
{
    GenericCollection FamilyTree { get; set; }
}

public class FamilyTreeFile : IFamilyTreeFile
{
    public GenericCollection FamilyTree { get; set; }
}
```

The code sample is generating the following XML file which is exactly as per my needs but i am unable to read it back using ReadXml method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FamilyTreeFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FamilyTree>
    <Member Name="Johny">
      <FamilyTree>
        <Member Name="Andy" />
        <Member Name="Adam">
          <FamilyTree>
            <Member Name="Davis">
              <FamilyTree>
                <Member Name="Simon" />
              </FamilyTree>
            </Member>
          </FamilyTree>
        </Member>
        <Member Name="Andrew" />
      </FamilyTree>
    </Member>
  </FamilyTree>
</FamilyTreeFile>
```

I need help in how can i restore it back efficiently?

**ADDED**

Upon adding new collection `Notes` in `IMember`

```
public interface IMember
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IMember Parent { get; set; }
    GenericCollection FamilyTree { get; set; }
    List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Note
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Implementing this property in `Member` class

```
[XmlArray("Notes")]
public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
```

I am unable to deserialize Notes information at this line.

```
var member = (IMember)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Isn't there any simple way to deserialize using XmlSerializer or any framework which handles everything itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working version of the GenericCollection.ReadXml method for you:

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    // no need to advace upfront so MoveToContent was taken out (would 
    // mess with subsequent inner deserializations anyway)

    // very important: there may be no members, so check IsEmptyElement
    if (reader.Name == "FamilyTree" && !reader.IsEmptyElement) 
    {
        do
        {
            if (reader.Name == "Member" && reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                Type type = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                  .Where(x => x.Name == reader.Name)
                                  .FirstOrDefault();
                if (type != null)
                {
                    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
                    var member = (IMember) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    this.Add(member);
                }
                continue; // to omit .Read because Deserialize did already 
                // advance us to next element
            }

            if (reader.Name == "FamilyTree" && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                break;

            reader.Read();
        } while (!reader.EOF);
    }
}
```

What you will most propably have missed out on in your version, was the fact that every call to a method of the XmlReader like `Read...()` or `Move...()` does advance it's reading position. The inner deserialization of member objects does the same.
Keeping this in mind, it should become clear that you simply cannot always issue a `Read()` at the beginning of the loop, but only at the very end. This way you can skip it with the `continue` keyword, in case some other code in the loop body (like `Deserialize()` in our case) did already advance the XmlReader. Same applies to `MoveToContent()` at the beginning of your version of the method. What I initially did miss out on too, is the fact that the collection of members can be empty. In that case the deserialization of GenericCollection has to be omitted completely, as (again) not to mess up the reader.

While this does deserialize the object instances and adds them to their respective lists, the references (the Parent field of the Member class in this example) are not reconstructed. Here is where things get tricky: A reference is esentially a memory adress. Being that, there is no point in serializing it's value and deserializing it back again. Because the objects will most propably reside in another memory location now, the deserialized address would be entirely wrong.

There are basically two ways to solve this:

1. The serialized objects could be constructed in a manner that automatically creates those references, when the objects are constucted or glued together. This way there is simply no serialization and deserialization needed. The drawback is: This is only possible for references that can be obtained in this manner (is the case in the current example)
2. Every object that can be target of a reference cold be extended by an identifier field, quite similar to a primary key in a database. This identifier (for example a guid) is then to be serialized and deserialized. Every referece field (the Parent field of the Member class in this example) is to be serialized as identifier value of the object it references (could be done by adding a helper field ParentID, which is set automatically by the setter of the Parent filed). When everything is deserialized, these references have to be reconstructed by walking the entire tree of objects. On the plus side, this enables one to reconstruct arbitrary references. But one has to be aware of this adding some real complexity to the code.

First approach could be done by:

Changing this in your Run() function...

```
var rootMember = new Member() { Name = "Johny"};
var member1 = new Member() { Name = "Andy" };
var member2 = new Member() { Name = "Adam" };
var member3 = new Member() { Name = "Andrew" };
var member4 = new Member() { Name = "Davis" };
var member5 = new Member() { Name = "Simon" };
```

...change property FamilyTree of class Member to this...

```
public GenericCollection FamilyTree
{
    get { return _FamilyTree; }
    set
    {
        _FamilyTree = value;
        _FamilyTree.Owner = this;
    }
}
```

... and insert this into class GenericCollection

```
private IMember _Owner;
public IMember Owner
{
    get { return _Owner; }
    set
    {
        _Owner = value;
        foreach (var member in this)
        {
            member.Parent = value;
        }
    }
}

public void Add(IMember item)
{
    item.Parent = Owner;
    base.Add(item);
}
```

The second approach is implemented in the following small console application:

```
class Program
{
    public static string FileName = @"FamilyTree.xml";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // make some members
        var rootMember = new Member() { Name = "Johny" };
        var member1 = new Member() { Name = "Andy" };
        var member2 = new Member() { Name = "Adam" };
        var member3 = new Member() { Name = "Andrew" };
        var member4 = new Member() { Name = "Davis" };
        var member5 = new Member() { Name = "Simon" };

        // construct some arbitrary references between them
        member1.Reference = member4;
        member3.Reference = member1;
        member5.Reference = member2;

        // let member 3 have some notes
        member3.Notes = new List<Note>();
        member3.Notes.Add(new Note() { Text = "note1" });
        member3.Notes.Add(new Note() { Text = "note2" });

        // add all of the to the family tree
        rootMember.FamilyTree.Add(member1);
        rootMember.FamilyTree.Add(member2);
        rootMember.FamilyTree.Add(member3);
        member2.FamilyTree.Add(member4);
        member4.FamilyTree.Add(member5);

        var familyTree = new GenericCollection() { rootMember };

        IFamilyTreeFile file = new FamilyTreeFile()
        {
            FamilyTree = familyTree
        };

        Console.WriteLine("--- input ---");
        Serialize(file);
        PrintTree(file.FamilyTree, 0);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("--- output ---");
        file = Deserialize();
        file.FamilyTree.RebuildReferences(file.FamilyTree); // this is where the refereces
        // are put  together again after deserializing the object tree.
        PrintTree(file.FamilyTree, 0);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintTree(GenericCollection c, int indent)
    {
        foreach (var member in c)
        {
            string line = member.Name.PadLeft(indent, ' ');
            if (member.Reference != null)
            {
                line += " (Ref: " + member.Reference.Name + ")";
                if (member.Notes != null && member.Notes.Count > 0)
                {
                    line += " (Notes: ";
                    foreach (var note in member.Notes)
                    {
                        line += note.Text + ",";
                    }
                    line += ")";
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            PrintTree(member.FamilyTree, indent + 4);
        }
    }

    public static void Serialize(IFamilyTreeFile obj)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FamilyTreeFile));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FileName))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }
    }

    public static IFamilyTreeFile Deserialize()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FamilyTreeFile));
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return (IFamilyTreeFile)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}

public interface IMember
{
    Guid ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    IMember Reference { get; set; }
    Guid ReferenceID { get; set; }
    GenericCollection FamilyTree { get; set; }
    List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    void RebuildReferences(GenericCollection in_Root);
}

[Serializable]
public class Member : IMember
{
    private GenericCollection _FamilyTree;
    private IMember _Reference;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public Guid ReferenceID { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IMember Reference
    {
        get { return _Reference; }
        set
        {
            ReferenceID = value.ID;
            _Reference = value;
        }
    }
    [XmlArray("Notes")]
    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    public GenericCollection FamilyTree
    {
        get { return _FamilyTree; }
        set
        {
            _FamilyTree = value;
            _FamilyTree.Owner = this;
        }
    }

    public Member()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        FamilyTree = new GenericCollection();
    }

    public void RebuildReferences(GenericCollection in_Root)
    {
        if (!ReferenceID.Equals(Guid.Empty))
            Reference = in_Root.FindMember(ReferenceID);

        FamilyTree.RebuildReferences(in_Root);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Note
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class GenericCollection : List<IMember>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    private IMember _Owner;
    public IMember Owner
    {
        get { return _Owner; }
        set
        {
            _Owner = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(IMember item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // no need to advace upfront so MoveToContent was taken out (would 
        // mess with subsequent inner deserializations anyway)

        // very important: there may be no members, so check IsEmptyElement
        if (reader.Name == "FamilyTree" && !reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            do
            {
                if (reader.Name == "Member" && reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    Type type = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                      .Where(x => x.Name == reader.Name)
                                      .FirstOrDefault();
                    if (type != null)
                    {
                        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
                        var member = (IMember)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        this.Add(member);
                    }
                    continue; // to omit .Read because Deserialize did already 
                    // advance us to next element
                }

                if (reader.Name == "FamilyTree" && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                    break;

                reader.Read();
            } while (!reader.EOF);
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (IMember rule in this)
        {
            var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            namespaces.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(rule.GetType());
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, rule, namespaces);
        }
    }

    public void RebuildReferences(GenericCollection in_Root)
    {
        foreach (IMember meber in this)
        {
            meber.RebuildReferences(in_Root);
        }
    }

    public IMember FindMember(Guid in_ID)
    {
        IMember FoundMember = null;
        foreach (IMember member in this)
        {
            if (member.ID.Equals(in_ID))
                return member;

            FoundMember = member.FamilyTree.FindMember(in_ID);
            if (FoundMember != null)
                return FoundMember;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public interface IFamilyTreeFile
{
    GenericCollection FamilyTree { get; set; }
}

public class FamilyTreeFile : IFamilyTreeFile
{
    public GenericCollection FamilyTree { get; set; }
}
```

A proof of concept for your addition to the original question is disclosed within this second example.

Comment: Thanks for giving direction but how can i retrieve the parent information which i have ignored due to serialization error? Kindly help in that also.

Comment: I have two different possible approaches in mind. Please bear with me for needing some time to implement and test. I will edit my answer when done...

Comment: Thanks for your effort much appreciated but kindly spare time to update your answer with 2nd approach. It will not only help me learn but others might find it helpful.

Comment: @Perter, thanks a lot, i will also evaluate the 2nd approach but currently i am still facing one issue in deserialization when i have added a new Collection to IMember, say Notes of type List<Note>, where Note is having one property named Text of type string. I have added a new block in my question in this regard.

Comment: I just corrected a bug in my original answer's code. Now everything should be fine.

Comment: My added question issue is still unsolved in my own big solution however in this piece of code for reference it is working fine. I have matched everything bit of it but no luck. Still after member deserialization the reader moves to `Notes` separately. Do you have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: @FSX: Sorry for the delay, but I was quite busy until now. Do you still have deserialization issues? It seems quite logical to me that Notes is deserialized after submember deserialization, given the order of fields in your example. Why is this an issue?

Comment: Its quite late but i had observed a very strange behavior that if you change the order of `Notes` property and declare it after `FamilyTree` property in `Member` class you might see the issue that i was discussing early on. It unable to deserialize `Notes` and goes in infinite loop. Why is it so?